# Filter Criteria or Decision Element in a Record Triggered Flow using an Update Record element

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, locking, updaterecord

After some advice on the best practice approach to updating records in a Flow.
I have a few flows that sum values of related records and update the parent with that summed value. I have set up the Update Record element with filter criteria to only update the record if the summed value is different from the value already on the parent record to reduce the amount of records getting updated constantly.

I was wondering if rather than using filter criteria compare the summed values I use decision element instead and if the values do match then route it to End otherwise update the parent. Would that decrease load / increase performance? I've run into a few Unable to Lock Row errors every now and then and am looking at how to avoid them.

Comment: I'd let DLRS do these rollups rather than Flow

Comment: Thanks, I do have a nightly DLRS that runs a full sync up just in case any errors occur throughout the day. Will look at moving them all to a scheduled hourly recalculation noting I can't install the the trigger as its on a managed package